# Why texture is displayed with the wrong color

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm rendering a skybox with a cube texture. But the color of the texture turned out to be wrong. The code below is used to load images. Is that because of the GL_RGB format? Any ideas about that?

```
protected void loadImageData()
{
    String fileDir;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        fileDir = "images/skybox/sky" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";

        try
        {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(fileDir));
            byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
            imageBuff[i] = GLBuffers.newDirectByteBuffer(data);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

setup texture:

```
    loadImageData();

    gl.glGenTextures(1, cubeTexBuff);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubeTexBuff.get(0));

    gl.glTexStorage2D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0, GL4.GL_RGB8, imageSize, imageSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL4.GL_RGB8, 
                imageSize, imageSize, 0, GL4.GL_RGB, GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBuff[i]);
    }

    gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR);
```

Original image:
[image: original image]

Mapping result:
[image: result with wrong color]

updated:

with this alternative provided: [enter link description here](https://github.com/elect86/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/modern-jogl-examples/src/tut16/gammaRamp/GammaRamp.java#L221-233) the color turns out to be correct finally, yet still a small problem (the direction becomes opposite), see the result below:

```
    String fileDir;
    TextureData texData = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        fileDir = "images/skybox/sky" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";

        try
        {
            texData = TextureIO.newTextureData(gl.getGLProfile(), 
                    new File(fileDir), false, TextureIO.JPG);

            texDataBuff[i] = texData.getBuffer();
            texDataBuff[i].rewind();

            //notice that the image used for skybox must be square
            imageSize = texData.getHeight();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    gl.glGenTextures(1, cubeTexBuff);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubeTexBuff.get(0));

    gl.glTexStorage2D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0, GL4.GL_RGB8, imageSize, imageSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL4.GL_RGB8, 
                imageSize, imageSize, 0, texData.getPixelFormat(), texData.getPixelType(), texDataBuff[i]);
    }

    gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR);
```

original image:

[image]

mapping result:

[image]

Comment: Try something like this https://github.com/elect86/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/modern-jogl-examples/src/tut16/gammaRamp/GammaRamp.java#L221-233

Comment: @elect Fixed. Thank you very much. But I still have no idea why I couldn't achieve that with my way.

Comment: Check the internalFormat, pixelFormat, pixelType and alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, flipping included

```
            ImageUtil.flipImageVertically(imageBuff[i]);
            {
                TextureData textureData = AWTTextureIO.newTextureData(gl3.getGLProfile(), textureBuffIm,
                        mipmap);

                gl3.glBindTexture(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, objects[Objects.texture.ordinal()]);
                {
                    int[] alignment = new int[1];
                    gl3.glGetIntegerv(GL3.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, alignment, 0);
//                System.out.println("alignment[0] "+alignment[0]);
//                System.out.println("textureData.getAlignment() "+textureData.getAlignment());
                    if (alignment[0] != textureData.getAlignment()) {

                        gl3.glPixelStorei(GL3.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, textureData.getAlignment());
                    }
                    {
                        gl3.glTexImage2D(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textureData.getInternalFormat(), textureData.getWidth(),
                                textureData.getHeight(), textureData.getBorder(), textureData.getPixelFormat(),
                                textureData.getPixelType(), textureData.getBuffer());
                    }
                    if (alignment[0] != textureData.getAlignment()) {

                        gl3.glPixelStorei(GL3.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, alignment[0]);
                    }
```

Remember that `AWTTextureIO` flips always the texture, so if you want to have it right, you flip it before, so that `AWTTextureIO` will flip it back and you will have the original image.
You can flip it back, if you still need to use that `imageBuffered`

Comment: You can flip the texture coordinates or use TextureIO which is faster and much more robust.